# Jump to activity without button click

Tags: java, android

I am trying to go to next activity. After checking if the GPS is enabled
without any button click I am trying to jump to next activity.
But its not working

Is there any way to jump to nexy activity after checking if GPS is enabled 
or after turning on GPS.

Help

Thanks.

**Main.java**

```
package app.example.joy;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Main extends Activity {

private LocationManager manager;
private LocationListener listner;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listner = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float latitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
            float longitude = (float) location.getLongitude();

            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, NextActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Long", longitude);
            i.putExtra("Lat", latitude);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    };

}

}
```

Comment: do u have both your activity name in manifest??

Comment: @Moulesh yes I have registered both activities.

Comment: You're not using `manager` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you've forgotten to even use the `LocationManager` that you instantiated. Try adding this line after instantiating the `listener` (at the end of your `onCreate`):

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

These will register for location updates using the named provider, and a pending intent.

Comment: not by both lines but by single GPS_provider line it worked thanks.

Comment: Cool, nice. I knew that there has to be something to trigger it :) Have fun coding.